# $i^{th}$ root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

So let's say you have $6+2i$ and you want to find $\sqrt[i]{6+2i}$. However what I would like is a more general formula for $$\sqrt[i]{a+bi}$$. I got this far $\sqrt[i]{a+bi}= e^{-iln(a+bi)}$ How do I continue?

Comment: In general, $z^c=e^{c\log(z)}$, where the logarithm function is multivalued.

Comment: And 1/i is just -i,  so plug that in for c and you're done.

Comment: That is slightly ambiguous. Is the i in i-th root a natural number or the imaginary unit?

Comment: i think it is $${{\rm e}^{\arctan \left( 1/3 \right) }}\cos \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( 40
 \right)  \right) -i{{\rm e}^{\arctan \left( 1/3 \right) }}\sin
 \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( 40 \right)  \right) 
$$

Comment: Slightly ambiguous?  It is hideously ambiguous because of the multivalued logarithm.  There are (countably many) infinite branches to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

The $i$th root of a complex number $z$ would be expressed as $z^{1/i}$, or $z^{-i}$. This, in turn, can be expressed as $$z^{-i}=\exp(-i\log z),$$ where $\log$ is interpreted as a suitable inverse of the exponential function. Since we can choose different branches of $\log$, we end up being able to choose different branches of the $i$th root function.

Answer (score 2):

In complex analysis one can define any power as $a^b=e^{b\log(a)}$ whenever $\log(a)$ is defined.
The exact value of $\log(a)$ depends on how you choose your branch cut.
For positive real $a$ there is a canonical choice, but otherwise it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

You will need the logarithm of $6+2i$ and you can then calculate
$$
\sqrt[i]{6+2i}
=
(6+2i)^{1/i}
=
(6+2i)^{-i}
=
e^{-i\log(6+2i)}.
$$
The multiple possible values of the logarithm correspond to having several roots.

Comment: How do you find at least one value of a complex logarithm?

Comment: @LatinWolf The easiest way is to write the number in polar form and then use Euler's formula. Please ask a follow-up question if you cannot find it on your own. Googling for the complex logarithm should lead you to formulas you might want to try.